# Binary search in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, search, dataframe

I'm searching for a large number of words in a big pandas dataframe and I have a problem with performance. Is there any way to binary search in the strings of a column in a pandas dataframe?

Right now my code is like this:

```
names = pd.DataFrame(data=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], index=range(0, 4), columns=['Name'])
sentence = 'There are two trees in the street.'

for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
    # Search for each word in all the names
    new_names = names[names['Name'].str.startswith(word)]
    # then do some operations on the names
```

But I needed a better performance for `names[names['Name'].str.startswith(word)]` and I thought I should find a way to binary search on the 'Name' column.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? You need to give way more specifics. Providing a sample DataFrame with some code that you have tried will go a long way.

Comment: @TedPetrou Thanks! I've changed the question a little bit.

Comment: There still isn't enough details to provide an answer. What is going on underneath the `iterrows`. You typically should avoid using `iterrows` at all costs. A sample dataframe with more info will go a long way.

Comment: @TedPetrou I added a sample data in the beginning. that `iterrows` is not important. I can use some other method for the next operations. the main problem is with the search in the dataframe when it becomes too large.

Comment: @AmirAhmad, you may want to check [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42684088/5741205)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues with this approach. First, `names['Name'].str.startswith(word)` is calculated for every word though it could be cached. Second, `startswith()` will match "There" for word "the". translating into code, it could be changed this way:

```
# calculate startword only once.
startword = names.apply(lambda row: row['Name'].split(" ", 1)[0])

for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
    # also, match by the full word only
    new_names = names[startword == word]
```

It can be even faster if startword was an index:

```
names.index = startword
for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
    # also, match by the full word only
    new_names = names.loc[word]
```

Comment: Thanks! this .loc[] returns a dataframe when there are multiple rows with that startword but when there is only one row, it returns some other data type which I should treat differently. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @AmirAhmad  just use `names.loc[[word]]` instead of `names.loc[word]`