# Python Pandas - check for substring containment and set new column to substring

Tags: python, string, pandas

I need to check for string containment and set the new column to the substring value.  I am currently trying this

```
df['NEW_COL'] = df['COL_TO_CHECK'].str.contains('|'.join(substring_list))
```

instead of returning the boolean true false for containment... I need to return the actual value from `substring_list` that matches to populate `df['NEW_COL]`

## SUBSTRINGS TO CHECK FOR

```
substring_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
```

## RESULTING DATAFRAME

```
OLD_COL              NEW_COL
apple pie            apple
black cherry         cherry
banana lemon drop    banana
```

Comment: Please share and example of input and output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [148]: df
Out[148]:
             OLD_COL
0          apple pie
1       black cherry
2  banana lemon drop

In [149]: pat = '.*({}).*'.format('|'.join(substring_list))

In [150]: pat
Out[150]: '.*(apple|banana|cherry).*'

In [151]: df['NEW_COL'] = df['OLD_COL'].str.replace(pat, r'\1')

In [152]: df
Out[152]:
             OLD_COL NEW_COL
0          apple pie   apple
1       black cherry  cherry
2  banana lemon drop  banana
```

Comment: what is the `r'\1'`?

Comment: `r'\1'` is the first captured RegEx group

Comment: what is your opinion of the method I used above?

`df['COL_TO_CHECK].apply(lambda x: [s for s in substring_list if s in x][0])`

Comment: @AranFreel, oh, i didn't notice that solution it in the comment. It looks quite good to me...

Comment: @AranFreel, there are better options if you are searching for words, not for substrings

Comment: I bet Wes Mckinney would prefer to use your method.

Comment: @AranFreel, it's always better to compare different methods againnst your real data set - this is the best approach IMO

Comment: @AranFreel, you may want to check answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683249/python-pandas-how-to-match-list-of-strings-with-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 3):

You are not being very insightful regarding what is your data and what you want, but the general principle is that you can use:

```
df['NEW_COL'] = df['COL_TO_CHECK'].apply(lambda x: do_something(x) if is_something(x) else x)
```

Or in your example:

```
substring_list = set(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'])
df['NEW_COL'] = df['OLD_COL'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split()).intersection(substring_list).pop())
```

`set` is faster :)

Comment: This solution works but I don't believe it is the best way to do it, create a list for every line doesn't seem efficient.


`df['COL_TO_CHECK].apply(lambda x: [s for s in substring_list if s in x][0])`

Comment: `set` is the best for containment checks, I knew that, duh :)

Comment: I think that my solution is more flexible

Comment: @MaxU No problem :) +1 back at you